# Soft Keyboard Hides Actionbar

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-softkeyboard, android-appbarlayout

I have a simple activity with a text view followed by two edit texts. When I start typing, the soft keyboard pushes layout up and hides the action bar, and I won't be able to select/copy/paste text.

**My activity looks like this:**

[image: Normal activity view]

When I start typing, the action bar gets hidden, like this - and more importantly, note that the normal copy paste bar is missing even though a text is highlighted:

[image: Missing action bar and the copy/paste bar]

What can I do to make sure the action bar does not hide?

- I have tried some other tips from SO (such as using scroll view) but none worked.
- The app is created using Android Studio 1.4.1 wizard with the Drawer Activity.
- In my activity manifest I am using adjustPan. I do not want to use adjustResize.

  `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`

**My activity is here:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/app_theme.app_bar_overlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/app_theme.popup_overlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_margin"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:text="My holiday story here." />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/activity_margin" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap_normal"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="My Holiday in Europe" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:text="My holiday story is blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah..." />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.magicparcel.app.mysampleapp.ui.CustomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/app_grey_500"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228514/keyboard-layout-hiding-android-action-bar

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use adjustPan, not adjustResize.

Comment: Did you try wrapping all the views in a ScrollView except the AppBarLayout?

Answer (score 6):

Try by adding `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` in toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/app_theme.popup_overlay" />
```

and for enable copy/paste in editText `Set android:textIsSelectable="true"` look more on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html

Comment: Hi, Just for some clarification. What we should do in case of any other View, which located above EditText fields. For example. we have several layouts above the EditText and we want to use adjustPan. In this case, while we selecting EditText, all views above moving up, and some of them (like ActionBar) hides. What I should do, to save some layouts above EditText in selecting, and let other moving up?

Comment: I didn't get you what you mean by this  **What I should do, to save some layouts above EditText in selecting, and let other moving up?**

Comment: not working for me, I am using the relative layout as root and toolbar

Answer (score 2):

**Step-1** : Remove `fitsSystemWindow` attribute from each view and add it in the activity tag in the manifest.

**Step-2** : `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` Remove this line from your linear layout. This is the code which is actually pushing the actionbar above.

These two steps solved my problem, Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Add you Toolbar inside AppBarLayout and add AppBarOverLay and PopOverlay themes.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```